# Display Python code and Jupyter notebook on wix website

Tags: web-deployment, velo

I'm writing a blog and I wanted to host a jupyter notebook on the wix website. What are the ways I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn your Jupyter Notebook to html that you can easily embed anywhere including Wix.

You can do it with [this](http://nbdev.fast.ai/export2html/).

Comment: The link is broken ...